# Why thread isn't starved in my example

Tags: java, multithreading

I cant understand why `t3` isn't getting starved, since there is only one lock and there is always some high priority thread waiting on it (as I see it, if `t1` acquire the lock, `t2` waits, and the opposite. So why does `t3` get the lock?

```
public class Starvation {

    public static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);
        final Object lock = new Object();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    latch.countDown();
                    latch.await();
                    while(count<100){
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            count++;
                            System.out.println("Count 1");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    latch.countDown();
                    latch.await();
                    while(count<100){
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            count++;
                            System.out.println("Count 2");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    latch.countDown();
                    latch.await();
                    while(count <100){
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            count++;
                            System.out.println("Count 3");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        t1.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        t2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        t3.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would note that you have the _exact same_ code three times - even in a test case it is good practice to create a `class` and three instances of it. Especially as then people don't have to do a manual diff to double check that you copy/pasted the code correctly...

Comment: Which OS are you running this on? Different OS'es have different policies for thread scheduling

Comment: Boris the Spider - you are right, next time i will.

jalf- maybe i'm wrong, but i don't think it is related to the OS .. since the JVM will schedule this threads.

Comment: realtime operating systems will schedule only the highest priority threads - but typical desktop/server operating systems(such as the ones your JVM run on) doesn't provide realtime guarantees, and rather distribute the CPU time each thread gets based on its priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cant understand why t3 isn't getting starved, since there is only one lock and there is always some high priority thread waiting on it (as i see it, if t1 acquire the lock, t2 waits, and the opposite.. so why t3 do get the lock?

The priority of typical thread implementations specifically will try hard not to starve threads.  If there are threads with higher priorities then they may run *more* than `t3` but `t3` will be given cycles.  Also, if your hardware has more than 2 CPU, t3 may be scheduled on a dormant CPU regardless of the priorities of the other threads.

For example, I've seen thread priority systems that keep the priority and a priority-counter.  Every time the thread gets a time slice its priority-counter is decremented.  Then when it reaches 0 it is put back to the max again.  This means that at some point a lower priority thread will have a equal or higher priority-counter and will get cycles.  But this is OS specific and there are probably other ways to accomplish it.

Really the priority of the threads should be considered to be a *hint* to the underlying OS.  I very rarely if ever have used priorities at all although I've written a lot of thread code.